# sql azure reporting solutions

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

Here's my setup:

- SQL Azure DB - This is the PaaS solution, not SQL Server running on an Azure VM.
- Single Page App (Angular.js) hosted on Azure Web App.

My needs:

- I'd like to find a packaged solution where we could allow user-configured reporting that could be saved by the user, for running later. Output would ideally be either CSV or PDF.

Initial thoughts:

- Could we create a SQL Server installation on an Azure VM, and use SSRS with the SQL Azure DB as the data source?
- Are there third party solutions that could meet these needs?

My research so far has shown one answer... migrate your data to SQL Server running on Azure VM, and use SSRS that way.

Any additional suggestions? I'm reluctant to do a data migration if I can avoid it.

Comment: I think the best solution without data migration is deploy SSRS to a VM and use SQL Azure DB as source.

Comment: i am sorry if i didnt understand correctly,if you have an onprem SSRS setup,then SSRS datasource can point to azure DB.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [PowerBi](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/), there are numerous examples on the web and here is an [overview](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-azure-and-power-bi/). What you basically get is an excel-like  environment with a lot of smart and easy visualizations. I am not sure how well it works, but there is a possibility to ask questions about your data in [natural language](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-q-and-a-tips/) as well.

It should be pretty easy to connect your [database to PowerBi](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-power-bi-to-visualize-and-explore-azure-sql-databases/), then your user can configure what kind of visualizations/report does he want to have.